# Chart.js in Angular Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, radar-chart

How can I change the stepsize for radar chart

```
   $scope.radar = {
        labels: chart.lastMonthMood.labels,
        data: [
            chart.lastMonthMood.labelsCount
        ],
        options: {
            scale: {
                reverse: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min:0,
                    stepSize: 1,
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

[Print screen of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oiJF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't understand your question. If you want to change the stepSize what about changing the field: `stepSize` inside the options object?